# Error in match.arg(type) : 'arg' must be of length 1

Tags: r

I am running this code in R:

```
tiff("f0ex_plot.tiff", height = 10, width = 20, units= "cm", type = c("windows", "cairo"), res = 300)
```

But I am receiving an error:

> Error in match.arg(type) : 'arg' must be of length 1

Any help?

Comment: Add some more information for better understanding.

Comment: Hi, this is plotting code for previous plotting: f0ex_plot <- grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol=2), do u need more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `Error in match.arg(type) : 'arg' must be of length 1` is associated with trying to pass more than one value to an argument that only accepts a single value. You are passing two values to the `type` argument. Try it with:

```
tiff("f0ex_plot.tiff", height = 10, width = 20, units= "cm", 
     type = "windows", res = 300)
  #... do something
dev.off()
```

Comment: thanks Jeffrey, it works!

Comment: @Al-JawharahAl-Zamil, glad to hear. Please flag as answered so the post will be indicated as resolved.